# Is there a way to change buttons created in the form editor using the given loop?

Tags: c#, loops, button

My form is composed of a 3x3 array and 9 buttons that were created using the form editor; each button is given an identifier such as btn1, btn2, all the way through to btn9. The methods DisableButton and EnableButton take a button as a parameter. Is there any way I could pass all the buttons to one method or the other using the for loops below?

```
        for (int r = 0; r < myArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < myArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                if (numericUpDown.Value > myArray[r, c] || myArray[r, c] == 0)
                    DisableButton(btn1);// new button parameter on each repeat
                else
                    EnableButton(btn1);                    
            }
        }
```

For the next repetition I want btn1 to change to btn2, then btn2 to btn3 and so on until each of the buttons are turned on or off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest putting all the buttons into array (or list) and then loop through them:

```
Button[] buttons =  { btn1, btn2/*, ...*/ };

// then you can do something like this
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
{
    EnableButton(buttons[i]);
}
// or
foreach(Button btn in buttons)
{
    EnableButton(btn);
}
```

Comment: Gets my vote - not too sure why he has a 3x3 array but a simple 1d array to loop through makes sense to me.

Comment: Well I'd loop through buttons and check wheter button should be enabled or disabled by some method (instead of using two loops for this)

Answer (score 0):

Follow following steps.

1. Get all button controls.
2. Loop through those.
3. Add condition according to your logic.
4. Call EnableButton() by passing current element of the loop.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: And if there are buttons other than these 9 on the form?  If you do this, at the very least, you'll want to ensure that all buttons are in a panel or other container and limit the search to just that container.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the array yourself easily enough:

```
Button[,] buttons = new Button[3, 3]
    { 
        { button1, button1, button1 }, 
        { button1, button1, button1 }, 
        { button1, button1, button1 }
    };
```